# Split a text file into two files, without losing revision history?

Tags: bazaar, version-control

So say I have `file.py` that I want to split into `file1.py` and `file2.py`.

What is the correct way to do this? Would it be to use the following?

```
bzr copy file.py file1.py
bzr copy file.py file2.py
bzr rm file.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently this isn't possible. This bug is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/269095).

Until then this is the only way (though you'll lose history for file2.py):

```
bzr mv file file1.py
cp file1.py file2.py
bzr add file2.py
```